# get SPECIFIC database row with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Ok so now I have this code where I'm retrieving data from db table:

```
<?php
        $link = mysql_connect('funki.fresh-tech.it', 'userns3e', '2w3rwrtwd');
        $db = mysql_select_db("funkireport", $link);

        $query = mysql_query("select * from machine", $link);

        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);

        var_dump($row);

        echo 'Connected successfully';
        mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

So in this table I have many rows and each has a "serial_number" column.... now what I'm trying to do is, get the row with the SPECIFIC serial_number (which I have as a variable)...

so for example

```
#   serial_number
1    AB1
2    AB2
3    AB3
4    AB4
5    AB5
```

and for example I have a variable `$product = AB2`

How can I GET from the database only the row that has "serial_number" = $product=AB2 ?

Please can somebody help me with this. Thank you

Comment: Please read mysql manuals about `where`-clause,

Comment: Reading a bit of the documentation before asking questions here always is a good idea. It can save you a lot of time, especially since you often learn things along the way that we were not actually looking for...

Comment: why would you have the `if( !$link )` after you have tried to execute the query? That ought to be before your call to `mysql_query` and indeed before your call to `mysql_select_db` probably too

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL [WHERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html) Clauses like that :-

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from machine where serial_number = '$product'", $link);
```

Your Query work like that :-

```
select * from machine where serial_number = 'AB2'
```

Answer (score -1):

Well it is actually not hard you just need to know what to do here. So as Rahautos said, you can use the `WHERE` clause. 
Your code(fixed):

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('funki.fresh-tech.it', 'userns3e', '2w3rwrtwd');
    $db = mysql_select_db("funkireport", $link);

    $query = mysql_query("select * from machine where serial_key='SERIAL KEY'", $link);

    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    echo $row['serial_key'];

    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

or instead you can use a form, input the key in the text field and get the results out with automation:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
        $link = mysqli_connect('funki.fresh-tech.it', 'userns3e', '2w3rwrtwd');
        $db = mysqli_select_db("funkireport", $link);
$key = $_POST['key']

        $query = mysql_query("select * from machine where serial_key='$key'", $link);

        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

        echo $row['serial_key'];
        mysql_close($link);
}
    ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<label>Key:</label>
<input type="text" name="key">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```